# Multiple users are using single coupon simultaneously

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I have created one **shopping cart rule** with uses per coupon "**1**" and uses per customer "**1**". For example, if user **A** adds product in cart and apply "**COUPON01**" on cart page. Also user **B** adds product in cart and apply same coupon "**COUPON01**" on cart page. Both users click on the place order same time and redirect to PayUPayment gateway for payment. Now both users get discount with single coupon.

How can I fix this issue in magento.(It is the case of simultaneous request to avail single coupon)

Comment: You can change your rule by adding an exception. Exception is make coupon available only for Logged in Users

Comment: As suggested your changes still I am facing same issue